# Is using `multiprocessing` still the easiest way to use make a subprocess that releases all memory when finished?

Tags: python, subprocess

This is a follow up to a stackoverflow answer from 2009

[How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python/1316799#1316799)

> Unfortunately (depending on your version and release of Python) some
>   types of objects use "free lists" which are a neat local optimization
>   but may cause memory fragmentation, specifically by making more and
>   more memory "earmarked" for only objects of a certain type and thereby
>   unavailable to the "general fund".
>
> The only really reliable way to ensure that a large but temporary use
>   of memory DOES return all resources to the system when it's done, is
>   to have that use happen in a subprocess, which does the memory-hungry
>   work then terminates. Under such conditions, the operating system WILL
>   do its job, and gladly recycle all the resources the subprocess may
>   have gobbled up. Fortunately, the multiprocessing module makes this
>   kind of operation (which used to be rather a pain) not too bad in
>   modern versions of Python.
>
> In your use case, it seems that the best way for the subprocesses to
>   accumulate some results and yet ensure those results are available to
>   the main process is to use semi-temporary files (by semi-temporary I
>   mean, NOT the kind of files that automatically go away when closed,
>   just ordinary files that you explicitly delete when you're all done
>   with them).

It's been 10 years since that answer, and I am wondering if there is a better way to create some sort of process/subprocess/function/method that releases all of it's memory when completed.

The motivation for this is an issue I am having, where a forloop creates a memory error, despite creating no new variables.

[Repeated insertions into sqlite database via sqlalchemy causing memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418825/repeated-insertions-into-sqlite-database-via-sqlalchemy-causing-memory-leak?noredirect=1#comment99577749_56418825)

It is insertion to a database. I know it's not the database itself that is causing the memory error because when I restart my runtime, the database is still preserved, but the crash doesn't happen until another several hundred iterations of the for loop.

Comment: If it's python that's giving the memory error, maybe see if invoking the garbage collector manually (say, every 50 or so iterations) fixes your problem (see [the `gc` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) for info on how to do that). I think it's likely that, while *your* code isn't creating any new variables, the code it's *calling* is - and this might clean that up. If the problem only happens after a few hundred iterations, it could be that the garbage collector simply isn't fast enough. Just a possibility, though

Comment: I have tried invoking the garbage collector every iteration. I haven't considered every say 50 iterations. Is there a reason why the latter may work better? Or was every 50 to save on speed?

Comment: Every 50 was to save on speed, yeah. Well, if that didn't help, maybe you can still use the other functions of the `gc` class and a debugger to see if you can isolate *what* is causing the problem, but otherwise I'm out of ideas